# Observable: If I never subscribe, do I have to garbage collect?

Tags: typescript, angular5, rxjs5

Given the below code sample:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ selector: 'foo' })
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  private foo: number;

  constructor () { }

  ngOnInit () {
    const timer$ = timer(0, 1000);
    timer$.pipe(
      tap((i: number) => this.foo = i)
    );
  }
}
```

I am creating an observable with an operator `tap` and just assigning to a private variable with no subscription.

1) Do I need to explicitly complete this observable or will that be handled transparently?

2) Does this behavior change for certain operators, like `map` or `switchMap`?

Comment: How would you unsubscribe without a `Subscription`?

Comment: I'm more or less asking if there's any garbage collection needed for the code sample. If this component is destroyed, I do not want the `tap` operation above to continue executing.

Comment: Never mind, I found a duplicate question. =_=